# Implantando single sign on usando AD

Tags: active-directory

É possível implementar single singn on, utilizando o AD? Como minhas aplicações legadas vão comunicar com o AD? Terá um WS?

Answer (score 1):

> É possível implementar single sign on, utilizando o AD?

Sim, é possível.

> Como minhas aplicações legadas vão comunicar com o AD?

Depende da aplicação legada. Em C#, a partir do *framework* 3.5, essa autenticação pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "SEUDOMINIO"))
{
    bool loginValido = pc.ValidateCredentials("usuario", "senha");
}
```

> Terá um WS?

Tudo depende de como você quer organizar a sua arquitetura. É possível sim fazer por WS, mas eu não recomendo ir por este caminho porque WS é uma abordagem antiga. Há outras melhores, como o [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).